# what does [1] mean in model.evaluate(X, Y)[1]

Tags: keras

The following codes are from a textbook called 'Deeplearning for everybody' and it is to predict diabetes based on the data from Pima indians. I wonder what the [1] at the end of the codes mean.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
import tensorflow as tf

np.random.seed(3)
tf.random.set_seed(3)

dataset = np.loadtxt('.\dataset\pima-indians-diabetes.csv', delimiter=',')

X = dataset[:, 0:8]
Y = dataset[:, 8]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, Y, epochs=200, batch_size=10)

print('\n Accuracy: %.4f' % (model.evaluate(X, Y)[1]))    # <---------
```

Comment: It's accessing the element at index 1. Note that container indices are 0-based in Python, so this is actually the 2nd element.

Comment: The dataset is as follows:

row 0: [  6.   , 148.   ,  72.   , ...,   0.627,  50.   ,   1.   ]
row 1: [  1.   ,  85.   ,  66.   , ...,   0.351,  31.   ,   0.   ]
row 2: [  8.   , 183.   ,  64.   , ...,   0.672,  32.   ,   1.   ]
       ...
You mean 'row 1' in the above dataset was used to evaluate? That's what I understood, so now I tried using 'row 2':  print('\n... model.evaluate(X, Y)[2])),... but then got an error, 'list index out of range'. Am I doing this right?

Comment: Can you print `type(model.evaluate(X, Y)`?

Comment: It says, 768/768 [==============================] - 0s 26us/step
Out[5]:  list

Comment: Ok, then you can get the length of the list with `len(model.evaluate(X, Y)`, and see why `[2]` isn't working.

Comment: It says, 768/768 [==============================] - 0s 26us/step
Out[8]: 2  ... only 2 lines, thus the error. The dataset sure has 768 rows, but this model.evaluate(X, Y) has only 2 lines. I did not separate train data from test data. I am confused.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) `.evaluate()` returns the loss value & metrics values for the model in test mode. Loss value & metrics looks like two things to me.

Comment: I would need more study to understand the documentation and your last comment. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Ok, good luck. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Keras `model.evaluate()` returns a list of aggregated metric values. Say you want to measure the loss, the accuracy, F1 score on your test data, then you would `compile` your model something like this: `model.compile(optimizer, loss, metrics=['accuracy', custom_f1_function], .. )` . Then these will be calculated for every sample (or batch) in the dataset and then reduced usually by taking the average. In the end you will get a list that has three elements: aggregated loss, aggregated accuracy, aggregated F1 score. In your code you are accessing the second element of this list, namely the accuracy.

(The order in `metrics=[..] determines the order in the output list!)

Comment: You gave me an explanation at my eye level. Wonderful, thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. :) Consider accepting my answer, if it resolved your question.